# Extract the output of cnn

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have trained a cnn model to classify images of dog and cat
it is giving 98% accuracy
But I want to visualize the output of cnn layer i.e the features from which my cnn is predicting whether it is a dog or a cat
If there any way to visualize the output of cnn?

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your model into two models:

Previous Model:

```py
input = Input(...)

# Your Layers
output = Dense(1)
old_model = Model(inputs=[input], output)
```

New Model:

```py
input = Input(...)

#Add the first layers and the CNN here
cnn_layer = Conv2D(...)
feature_extraction_model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=cnn_layer)

input_cnn = Input(...) # The shape of your CNN output

# Add the classification layer here
output = Dense(1)

classifier_model = Model(inputs=[input_cnn], outputs=output)
```

Now you define the new model as a combination of: **feature_extraction_model** and **classifier_model**

```py
new_model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=classifier_model(input_cnn))

# Train the model
new_model.fit(x, y)
```

Now you can have access to the CNNlayer post training:

```py
cnn_output = feature_extraction_model.predict(x)
```